# Entity Framework does not pick up the value from newly added column

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

Model :

```
//Auto generated by MVC Model
public partial class user
{    
    public int Ref { get; set; }
    public string First_Name { get; set; }
    public bool isAdmin { get; set; } //the problem
}
```

Database:

```
Ref | First_Name | isAdmin
1   |   Admin    |   1
2   |   Bob      |   0
```

C#:

```
var u1= db.users.Find(1); //get Admin
var ia1= u1.isAdmin; //return false (0)
var adminList = db.users.Where(i => i.isAdmin == true).ToList(); //return error
```

Error :

> System.NotSupportedException: 'The specified type member 'isAdmin' is
>   not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members,
>   and entity navigation properties are supported.'

======

I did try deleting ADO.NET Model and re-add it, restart my machine but no luck MVC model is still not picking up the correct value from the database. (although it picks up the new column).

I did alter my database structure many times and it was fine, one thing that I did differently to then is I changed the .NET framework target from 4.6 to 4.5.2, will this be the one causing this issue?

Back to the primary question is why the model does not return the correct value, and why it gets not supported exception when I query by (isAdmin == true) - this should be the lead, but im clueless of what's going on.

Comment: I'm curious - what data type is `isAdmin` in the database?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Im using MS SQL Server, it is bit in database and mapped as bool in model | for the records I have been sticking with this data type for several projects and I believe should not be the issue.

Comment: is there any errors or warning in visual studio error list window regarding the Model?

Comment: So, does the problem go away if you change .NET Framework target back to 4.6?

Comment: Looking through my code, I have a model property of type bool which is based on a database field of type bit. In my lambda function I don't have the `== true` part. For example I have `.Where(x => x.IsLeave)`. I don't think that should make a difference though. In fact it builds whether or not I put `== true` in there or not

Comment: @AmrElgarhy none, no warning nor error at all.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu currently trying, however at the end im required to have it on 4.5

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes they are the same

Comment: What is the [logged SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469464(v=vs.113).aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to resolve the issue without knowing exactly of whats going on but my best guess is the cache (or whatever it is) of the ADO.NET/Entity Framework.

**Simply create an ADO.NET Model with a different name, then it works and properly load the data just fine from the database.**

If anyone has hypothetical explanation of this case, feel free to jot it down in the comment.